# unable to find driver - lamp debian

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my php sample script:

```
<?php
try{
    $db=new PDO('mysql:dbname=_mydb;host=localhost', 'root', 'xxxxxx');
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

And I have returned:

```
could not find driver
```

Also:

```
user@nbook:~$  php -i|grep PDO
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
```

This is my phpinfo:

```
PHP Version 5.6.9-0+deb8u1

System  Linux nbook 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64
Build Date  Jun 5 2015 11:03:32
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini
PHP API 20131106
PHP Extension   20131226
Zend Extension  220131226
Zend Extension Build    API220131226,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20131226,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
Zend logo This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
Configuration

apache2handler

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    webmaster@localhost
Hostname:Port   nbook.home:80
User/Group  www-data(33)/33
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /etc/apache2
Loaded Modules  core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_dnssd mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_setenvif mod_status
Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0
Apache Environment

Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   localhost
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
SERVER_NAME localhost
SERVER_ADDR ::1
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR ::1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/html
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/info.php
REMOTE_PORT 35615
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /info.php
SCRIPT_NAME /info.php
HTTP Headers Information

HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /info.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost
Connection  keep-alive
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
HTTP Response Headers
bcmath

BCMath support  enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
bcmath.scale    0   0
bz2

BZip2 Support   Enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support   bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version   1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
calendar

Calendar support    enabled
Core

PHP Version 5.6.9-0+deb8u1
Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   0   0
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset UTF-8   UTF-8
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,    pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
display_errors  Off Off
display_startup_errors  Off Off
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
enable_post_data_reading    On  On
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 22527   22527
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  Off Off
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20131226  /usr/lib/php5/20131226
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear    .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
input_encoding  no value    no value
internal_encoding   no value    no value
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_encoding no value    no value
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
sys_temp_dir    no value    no value
track_errors    Off Off
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
zend.detect_unicode On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On
zend.multibyte  Off Off
zend.script_encoding    no value    no value
ctype

ctype functions enabled
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Berlin
Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   no value    no value
dba

DBA support enabled
libdb header version    Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September 9, 2013)
libdb library version   Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September 9, 2013)
Supported handlers  cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile qdbm
Directive   Local Value Master Value
dba.default_handler flatfile    flatfile
dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.1
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
ereg

Regex Library   Bundled library enabled
exif

EXIF Support    enabled
EXIF Version    1.4 $Id: 5504545b9be3379c5244b371d825eb64659eb5f5 $
Supported EXIF Version  0220
Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF
Directive   Local Value Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel   JIS JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola    JIS JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel   UCS-2LE UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola    UCS-2BE UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis no value    no value
exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fileinfo

fileinfo support    enabled
version 1.0.5
libmagic    517
filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 86120bba568c551914a35636ec408f1e7e66af32 $
Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value
ftp

FTP support enabled
gettext

GetText Support enabled
hash

hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5
iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.19
Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    no value    no value
iconv.internal_encoding no value    no value
iconv.output_encoding   no value    no value
json

json support    enabled
json version    1.3.6
JSON-C headers version  0.11.99
JSON-C library version  0.11.99
libxml

libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version   20901
libXML streams  enabled
mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 5.9.5
Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input no value    no value
mbstring.http_output    no value    no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value
mhash

MHASH support   Enabled
MHASH API Version   Emulated Support
openssl

OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
Directive   Local Value Master Value
openssl.cafile  no value    no value
openssl.capath  no value    no value
pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.35 2014-04-04
Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers no value
Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.2
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: a861a034647a6e80ebad0851e018adee293647fb $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   enabled
OpenSSL support enabled
Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On
posix

Revision    $Id: 5d20de77687b7d961b15450873fa23b9e64a136a $
readline

Readline Support    enabled
Readline library    EditLine wrapper
Directive   Local Value Master Value
cli.pager   no value    no value
cli.prompt  \b \>   \b \> 
Reflection

Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: eff8bdc65b0beaf8f4ade6f06f848e6d43dfd826 $
session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php5/sessions  /var/lib/php5/sessions
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
shmop

shmop support   enabled
SimpleXML

Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: e0de6ee7ef8280a12d77d76f1f971a944cbc8090 $
Schema support  enabled
soap

Soap Client enabled
Soap Server enabled
Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 86400   86400
sockets

Sockets Support enabled
SPL

SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
standard

Dynamic Library Support enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value
sysvmsg

sysvmsg support enabled
Revision    $Id: 1e821e8a0cbb868efec453560ba303e04f3a1db2 $
tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled
wddx

WDDX Support    enabled
WDDX Session Serializer enabled
xml

XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.9.1
xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled
xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled
Zend OPcache

Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup OK
Shared memory model mmap
Cache hits  3
Cache misses    3
Used memory 5468496
Free memory 61640368
Wasted memory   0
Interned Strings Used memory    317304
Interned Strings Free memory    3877000
Cached scripts  3
Cached keys 3
Max keys    3907
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts  0
Manual restarts 0
Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.load_comments   1   1
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.optimization_level  0xFFFFFFFF  0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On
zip

Zip enabled
Extension Version   $Id: f9f12af1274212b9f22867472e4aa57eab4bb4cf $
Zip version 1.12.5
Libzip version  0.11.2
zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.8
Linked Version  1.2.8
Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value
Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm
Environment

Variable    Value
APACHE_RUN_DIR  /var/run/apache2
APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
LANG    C
APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
APACHE_RUN_GROUP    www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR  /var/log/apache2
PWD /
PHP Variables

Variable    Value
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    localhost
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate, sdch
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2
_SERVER["PATH"] /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  localhost
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  ::1
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  ::1
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/html
_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"]   http
_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]   no value
_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/html
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] webmaster@localhost
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /var/www/html/info.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  35615
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /info.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /info.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /info.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]   1436442195.621
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1436442195
PHP Credits

PHP Group
Thies C. Arntzen, Stig Bakken, Shane Caraveo, Andi Gutmans, Rasmus Lerdorf, Sam Ruby, Sascha Schumann, Zeev Suraski, Jim Winstead, Andrei Zmievski
Language Design & Concept
Andi Gutmans, Rasmus Lerdorf, Zeev Suraski, Marcus Boerger
PHP Authors
Contribution    Authors
Zend Scripting Language Engine  Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski, Stanislav Malyshev, Marcus Boerger, Dmitry Stogov, Xinchen Hui, Nikita Popov
Extension Module API    Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski, Andrei Zmievski
UNIX Build and Modularization   Stig Bakken, Sascha Schumann, Jani Taskinen
Windows Port    Shane Caraveo, Zeev Suraski, Wez Furlong, Pierre-Alain Joye, Anatol Belski
Server API (SAPI) Abstraction Layer Andi Gutmans, Shane Caraveo, Zeev Suraski
Streams Abstraction Layer   Wez Furlong, Sara Golemon
PHP Data Objects Layer  Wez Furlong, Marcus Boerger, Sterling Hughes, George Schlossnagle, Ilia Alshanetsky
Output Handler  Zeev Suraski, Thies C. Arntzen, Marcus Boerger, Michael Wallner
SAPI Modules
Contribution    Authors
AOLserver   Sascha Schumann
Apache 1.3 (apache_hooks)   Rasmus Lerdorf, Zeev Suraski, Stig Bakken, David Sklar, George Schlossnagle, Lukas Schroeder
Apache 1.3  Rasmus Lerdorf, Zeev Suraski, Stig Bakken, David Sklar
Apache 2.0 Filter   Sascha Schumann, Aaron Bannert
Apache 2.0 Handler  Ian Holsman, Justin Erenkrantz (based on Apache 2.0 Filter code)
Caudium / Roxen David Hedbor
CGI / FastCGI   Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov
CLI Edin Kadribasic, Marcus Boerger, Johannes Schlueter, Moriyoshi Koizumi, Xinchen Hui
Continuity  Alex Leigh (based on nsapi code)
Embed   Edin Kadribasic
FastCGI Process Manager Andrei Nigmatulin, dreamcat4, Antony Dovgal, Jerome Loyet
ISAPI   Andi Gutmans, Zeev Suraski
litespeed   George Wang
NSAPI   Jayakumar Muthukumarasamy, Uwe Schindler
phpdbg  Felipe Pena, Joe Watkins, Bob Weinand
phttpd  Thies C. Arntzen
pi3web  Holger Zimmermann
Sendmail Milter Harald Radi
thttpd  Sascha Schumann
tux Sascha Schumann
WebJames    Alex Waugh
Module Authors
Module  Authors
BC Math Andi Gutmans
Bzip2   Sterling Hughes
Calendar    Shane Caraveo, Colin Viebrock, Hartmut Holzgraefe, Wez Furlong
COM and .Net    Wez Furlong
ctype   Hartmut Holzgraefe
cURL    Sterling Hughes
Date/Time Support   Derick Rethans
DB-LIB (MS SQL, Sybase) Wez Furlong, Frank M. Kromann
DBA Sascha Schumann, Marcus Boerger
DOM Christian Stocker, Rob Richards, Marcus Boerger
enchant Pierre-Alain Joye, Ilia Alshanetsky
ereg    Rasmus Lerdorf, Jim Winstead, Jaakko Hyvätti
EXIF    Rasmus Lerdorf, Marcus Boerger
fileinfo    Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre Alain Joye, Scott MacVicar, Derick Rethans
Firebird driver for PDO Ard Biesheuvel
FTP Stefan Esser, Andrew Skalski
GD imaging  Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Jim Winstead, Jouni Ahto, Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre-Alain Joye, Marcus Boerger
GetText Alex Plotnick
GNU GMP support Stanislav Malyshev
Iconv   Rui Hirokawa, Stig Bakken, Moriyoshi Koizumi
IMAP    Rex Logan, Mark Musone, Brian Wang, Kaj-Michael Lang, Antoni Pamies Olive, Rasmus Lerdorf, Andrew Skalski, Chuck Hagenbuch, Daniel R Kalowsky
Input Filter    Rasmus Lerdorf, Derick Rethans, Pierre-Alain Joye, Ilia Alshanetsky
InterBase   Jouni Ahto, Andrew Avdeev, Ard Biesheuvel
Internationalization    Ed Batutis, Vladimir Iordanov, Dmitry Lakhtyuk, Stanislav Malyshev, Vadim Savchuk, Kirti Velankar
JSON    Omar Kilani, Scott MacVicar
LDAP    Amitay Isaacs, Eric Warnke, Rasmus Lerdorf, Gerrit Thomson, Stig Venaas
LIBXML  Christian Stocker, Rob Richards, Marcus Boerger, Wez Furlong, Shane Caraveo
mcrypt  Sascha Schumann, Derick Rethans
MS SQL  Frank M. Kromann
Multibyte String Functions  Tsukada Takuya, Rui Hirokawa
MySQL driver for PDO    George Schlossnagle, Wez Furlong, Ilia Alshanetsky, Johannes Schlueter
MySQL   Zeev Suraski, Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov
MySQLi  Zak Greant, Georg Richter, Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel
MySQLnd Andrey Hristov, Ulf Wendel, Georg Richter, Johannes Schlüter
OCI8    Stig Bakken, Thies C. Arntzen, Andy Sautins, David Benson, Maxim Maletsky, Harald Radi, Antony Dovgal, Andi Gutmans, Wez Furlong, Christopher Jones, Oracle Corporation
ODBC driver for PDO Wez Furlong
ODBC    Stig Bakken, Andreas Karajannis, Frank M. Kromann, Daniel R. Kalowsky
OpenSSL Stig Venaas, Wez Furlong, Sascha Kettler, Scott MacVicar
Oracle (OCI) driver for PDO Wez Furlong
pcntl   Jason Greene, Arnaud Le Blanc
Perl Compatible Regexps Andrei Zmievski
PHP Archive Gregory Beaver, Marcus Boerger
PHP Data Objects    Wez Furlong, Marcus Boerger, Sterling Hughes, George Schlossnagle, Ilia Alshanetsky
PHP hash    Sara Golemon, Rasmus Lerdorf, Stefan Esser, Michael Wallner, Scott MacVicar
Posix   Kristian Koehntopp
PostgreSQL driver for PDO   Edin Kadribasic, Ilia Alshanetsky
PostgreSQL  Jouni Ahto, Zeev Suraski, Yasuo Ohgaki, Chris Kings-Lynne
Pspell  Vlad Krupin
Readline    Thies C. Arntzen
Recode  Kristian Koehntopp
Reflection  Marcus Boerger, Timm Friebe, George Schlossnagle, Andrei Zmievski, Johannes Schlueter
Sessions    Sascha Schumann, Andrei Zmievski
Shared Memory Operations    Slava Poliakov, Ilia Alshanetsky
SimpleXML   Sterling Hughes, Marcus Boerger, Rob Richards
SNMP    Rasmus Lerdorf, Harrie Hazewinkel, Mike Jackson, Steven Lawrance, Johann Hanne, Boris Lytochkin
SOAP    Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov
Sockets Chris Vandomelen, Sterling Hughes, Daniel Beulshausen, Jason Greene
SPL Marcus Boerger, Etienne Kneuss
SQLite 3.x driver for PDO   Wez Furlong
SQLite3 Scott MacVicar, Ilia Alshanetsky, Brad Dewar
Sybase-CT   Zeev Suraski, Tom May, Timm Friebe
System V Message based IPC  Wez Furlong
System V Semaphores Tom May
System V Shared Memory  Christian Cartus
tidy    John Coggeshall, Ilia Alshanetsky
tokenizer   Andrei Zmievski, Johannes Schlueter
WDDX    Andrei Zmievski
XML Stig Bakken, Thies C. Arntzen, Sterling Hughes
XMLReader   Rob Richards
xmlrpc  Dan Libby
XMLWriter   Rob Richards, Pierre-Alain Joye
XSL Christian Stocker, Rob Richards
Zip Pierre-Alain Joye, Remi Collet
Zlib    Rasmus Lerdorf, Stefan Roehrich, Zeev Suraski, Jade Nicoletti, Michael Wallner
```

What can be the problem? Thanks for the support.

Comment: You don't have the mysql_pdo library enabled or installed?

Answer (score 1):

From your phpinfo command

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers no value
Phar
```

You may have PHP cli compiled with the proper driver, but you don't have your interpreter (is it PHP-FPM?) setup with the PDO mysql driver.

Comment: so how can I do it? I am using Debian

Comment: I have php interpreter

Comment: This question would be better suited for serverfault, as it is a server/configuration related question, not a programming one. As a quick note, try apt-get install php5-mysql and php5-pdo

Comment: Regretfully, you will have to ask your question on a server related forum.